Attribution of Payment for Mortgage/Loan Interest (Form 1098)
The 1098 Mortgage Interest Statement is a form that describes the amount of interest paid by an entity on an outstanding mortgage loan. What are the legal requirements for this interest to be attributed to a given entity?
In general, mortgage payments tend to be paid via ACH wire transfer or with a paper check. Is it legally necessary that the accounts from which the funds are drawn be bound to the same entity? Must the entity making the payment (and receiving the 1098 form) necessarily be named on the loan?
Perhaps that seems obvious, or a trivial question. But I am wondering of a scenario where money is exchanged between individuals before the payments are made. In this case who receives the interest "credits" for write-off on their taxes?
Considering the following:
EntityA has an outstanding mortgage loan and is solely named on the official paperwork
EntityB has a bank account that is registered solely to EntityB
EntityA sends EntityB funds
EntityB executes an ACH wire transfer to pay an installment of EntityA's mortgage


Is it legally the case that EntityA technically never made a mortgage payment since it was executed by EntityB?

Who receives the 1098 form in this case?

Would it change anything if EntityA and EntityB were named on the bank account that made the ACH transfer for payment?

Can a payment on EntityA's loan be made via proxy by EntityB in general? In other words, can the payment be accompanied by metadata that says "payment on behalf of EntityA" so EntityA is correctly credited with making the payment?


Fundamentally creditors are unlikely to care where funding comes from so long as the payments are made. My question is specifically regarding how the tax accounting is done regarding credit reporting and the 1098 "interest credits" (for tax write-off purposes) are handled.
Objectively (without any knowledge on the subject of tax in this area) it feels as if EntityA's creditor would track successful payment regardless of whom was making the payments. However, I am unsure of whom is credited with the "N dollars of interest paid" 1098 forms?

The 1098 is sent to the mortgage holder(s) and is linked to the mortgage holder(s) social security number(s). How the payments got to the mortgage holder is irrelevant to the situation.

@JonCuster That was quick. So regardless of how payment is made the mortgage holder (by that I assume you mean the individual or business and not the creditor) receives the 1098 form for tax accounting purposes. Origin of funding does not matter. This is more or less what I was expecting.

I think you are putting together accounting issues for the payer with distribution of the 1098, which is solely to the mortgagor.


What are the legal requirements for this interest to be attributed to a given entity?

The 1098 is issued to the entity responsible for paying the loan, i.e.: the entity on the note. For mortgages, this is usually the entity on the deed.

In general, mortgage payments tend to be paid via ACH wire transfer or with a paper check. Is it legally necessary that the accounts from which the funds are drawn be bound to the same entity?

No, they just have to be authorized. I.e.: the account owner must authorize the payments.

Must the entity making the payment ... necessarily be named on the loan?

No, the entity responsible for making the payment is.

Must the entity  ... (and receiving the 1098 form) necessarily be named on the loan?

Yes. The 1098 goes to the entity responsible for payment of the interest.


But I am wondering of a scenario where money is exchanged between individuals before the payments are made. In this case who receives the interest "credits" for write-off on their taxes?

This is a completely separated issue. See the IRC Sec. 163(h)(3):

The term “acquisition indebtedness” means any indebtedness which—
(I) is incurred in acquiring, constructing, or substantially improving any qualified residence of the taxpayer, and
(II) is secured by such residence.

Note: the taxpayer is not required to (fully) own the qualified residence.
See also the 26 CFR 1.163-1(b):

Interest paid by the taxpayer on a mortgage upon real estate of which he is the legal or equitable owner, even though the taxpayer is not directly liable upon the bond or note secured by such mortgage, may be deducted as interest on his indebtedness.

It is entirely possible, for example, that children will live in a house co-owned by their parents, paying off the mortgage co-signed by the parents, and claiming the interest deduction, without actually fully owning the house.
An explanation to the facts must be attached to the tax returns of both the 1098 recipients and the claimants.
